# Auth0 test account best practices

Tags: security, authentication, testing, automated-tests, auth0

I am working on a project using Auth0 for authentication, and I am starting to write client side tests for this project.  I would like to create a test account for this project that can allow a script to regularly and automatically run through different scenarios in the application.

The problem is that I'd like to run these tests on a stack with actual customer data.  This means the credentials/password for this account need to be hidden from the public.  I should be able to rotate these credentials easily as well so nobody I work with has permanent access to the customer data.  I'd also like to keep any credentials out of my checked in codebase, in case that leaks to the public.

What are some best practices for this situation?  Are there similar problems that have solutions I can use for inspiration?

Answer (score 0):

Testing in production is like, my favourite thing in the world. So, in order to

> run these tests on a stack with actual customer data

I would suggest some of the monitoring good practices, we (my company) follow. Since those are pretty much a specific subset of your

> different scenarios in the application

First one is to consider a CI server (like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/)), which will

> allow a script to regularly and automatically run

based on the business case you cover. For example, we hit `login` every 5 mins, but `edit_profile` every 15 mins. As to

> credentials/password for this account need to be hidden from the public. I should be able to rotate these credentials easily as well so nobody I work with has permanent access to the customer data. I'd also like to keep any credentials out of my checked in codebase, in case that leaks to the public.

we use a combo of those for [injecting secrets](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs) in our CI jobs:

- [Credentials](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) plugin - provides a centralized way to define credentials that can be used by your Jenkins instance, plugins and build jobs.
- [Credentials Binding](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) plugin - allows you to configure your build jobs to inject credentials as environment variables.
- [Plain Credentials](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plain+Credentials+Plugin) plugin - a plugin dependency required by the Credentials Binding plugin.

Next practice we try to follow is to have dedicated *static* users for our each check type, don't rely on demo or sales ones. Other thing we are very careful is to rely mostly on `read`s and not `write`s. Since the data generated via such checks is quite substantial.

Logs also require some disk space after a while, so we prefer to store those in S3 bucket.